# jQuery Multiple Slide Toggles

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#event1').click(function(){
        $('.eventdetails').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

My problem is having multiple `events` toggling multiple `eventdetails` at once. I considered having a different ID for each. However I couldn't figure out how to still be able to create more events via a HTML form, and not have every event toggle every event details.

The relevant HTML for the page:

```
<p class="event" id="event1">Hawksbury 1</p>
<div class="eventdetails" >
    <form name="event" method="post" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div>Transport</div></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="transport" id="transport"> </input></td>
                <td><div>Accomodation</div></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="accomodation" id="accomodation"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div>Food</div></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="food" id="food"> </input></td>
                <td><div>Competing</div></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="competing"     id="competing"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
            <td><input type="submit"></input></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML so that we can see which elements have the click and which have the toggle. Maybe it's very easy to solve.

Comment: I just added the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to query using class instead of id:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.event').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.eventdetails').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WMzKm/

In case you not familiar with jquery yet: $(this).next() is return the following sibling of the element you are clicking on. See more [here](http://api.jquery.com/next/).